# Dynamically change JSP page content without buttons

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I've written a code that dynamically fills a drop down list from an SQL database.
Next, I need to change the content of the page depending on user selection in real-time (no buttons), perhaps show another label, or even show another drop down list that also gets it's values from an SQL DB depending on the previous selection etc..
Here is my code

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%ResultSet resultset = null;
Connection conn;%>
<HTML>
<%
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-O708F3G\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=master",
                "user", "pswd");

        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from RTable");
%>
<h1> Drop down list</h1>
    <select name="projectname">
        <%  while (resultset.next()) {%>
        <option><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
<%
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("error"+e);
    }
%>
</HTML>
```

After all the selections are done, I will display a "submit" button that sends the selected data to a back-end servlet (I know how to do that once the button is there).

Comment: You can call a function on the onchange of select and pass the selected values id, from that you can make an ajax request which will return you the data and you can create label, dropdown from that data.

Comment: Bear with me, I am new to JSP web development, are you saying there is a change listener running at all times ?

Comment: write your code in function and call it in select onchange event. you may use ajax.

Comment: You can add a change listner to select

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to help, but you assume that I know all of this.
I am now to web development, I have not used ajax before.
Is that solution you're talking about going to run on the front-end or back-end, because it does not make sense for it to run on the back-end, the whole point of my question is updating the page without needing to go back to the back-end servlet, hence the "no button" request.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following javascript function and call it on the onchange event of your `<select>` element:

```
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
    }
    </script>
//Your JSP Code
    <select name="projectname" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
        <%  while (resultset.next()) {%>
        <option value="<%= resultset.getString(2)%>"><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
```

Please check the code for the value attribute of your `<option>`, it might be wrong; but the other code will work fine. I have added the 'id' and 'onchange' attributes for the `<select>` tag.